# tomcat embedded jndi data source maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I add to pom.xml tomcat embedded and his created in the target folder. I don't know how to configure jndi in tomcat, in target/tomcat/conf i don't have contex.xml when i manually created it and add

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
  global="jdbc/MyDB"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
  username="hr"
  password="oracle"

  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="20"
  minIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"/>
```

and clean maven project everything disappear. Where to put configuration file in maven project and how to properly configure it.

Comment: you should be having `context.xml` inside `tomcat/conf` folder, do not go inside `target`

Comment: yes but tomcat folder is inside target because its embedded